# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 503

Tags: android, android-volley

**Android Volley POST method error**

BasicNetwork.performRequest: **Unexpected response code 503**

Post request send to the server.

```
Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

jsonParams.put("LoginForm[email]",email);
jsonParams.put("LoginForm[password]",password);
jsonParams.put("TOKEN", token);

JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.POST, URL,
        new JSONObject(jsonParams),
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // on Response
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // on Error Response
            }
        }) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        headers.put("User-agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"));
        return headers;
    }
};
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
requestQueue.add(postRequest);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: can you paste what request you send via postman

Answer (score 1):

503 is due to ..

**503 Service Unavailable**

The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD handle the response as it would for a 500 response.

Refer [this](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: But There are no any server error in this api because if I am using this api via postman then it is working fine.

Comment: @RanjeetKushwaha refer [this](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/503error.htm) also.. This will give you an idea

Comment: @RanjeetKushwaha According to this [thread](http://androidqueries.com/%93delete-account-failed-%96-503-service-unavailable%94-error-message-android-31391.html) try clearing the cache, Reboot and try again

Comment: @RanjeetKushwaha Also check if you are making mutlple requests at same time.. If the url is signed it expires pretty quickly too